# How can I hide the active language in the language switcher block?

Tags: i18n-l10n

I have a site with two languages, but it's pointless to show the name of the currently selected language in the language switcher block.  How can I hide it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The links generated by the [Language API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!language.api.php/7) are alterable via [`hook_language_switch_links_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!language.api.php/function/hook_language_switch_links_alter/7), so you can do this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_language_switch_links_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_language_switch_links_alter(array &$links, $type, $path) {
  global $language;

  unset($links[$language->language]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner way is to do the following:

```
use Drupal\Core\Language\LanguageInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Url;

/**
 * Implements hook_language_switch_links_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_general_language_switch_links_alter(array &$links, $type, Url $url): void {
  $current_language = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage();
  
  // Make sure the language is instance of language interface.
  if (!$current_language instanceof LanguageInterface) {
    return;
  }
  
  // Make sure the language option exists.
  if (isset($links[$current_language->getId()])) {
    unset($links[$current_language->getId()]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Drupal 8]:**

Implement hook_language_switch_links_alter in a custom module like this:

```
 /**
 * Perform alterations on language switcher links.
 *
 * A language switcher link may need to point to a different path or use a
 * translated link text before going through the link generator, which will
 * just handle the path aliases.
 *
 * @param array $links
 *   Nested array of links keyed by language code.
 * @param string $type
 *   The language type the links will switch.
 * @param \Drupal\Core\Url $url
 *   The URL the switch links will be relative to.
 */
function hook_language_switch_links_alter(array &$links, $type, \Drupal\Core\Url $url) {
  $language_interface = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage();
  $current_language_id = $language_interface->getId();
  unset($links[$current_language_id]);
}
```